# cURL to JSON in PHP - POST not working

Tags: php, json, curl

I have the following cURL command, to add an image to my server, which works just fine:

```
curl -i -X POST -u user:pw -F 'post[image]'=@image.jpg http://domain.com/post.json
```

Now I want to make this work in PHP. I seem to get everything working, except for the 'post[image]'=@image.jpg part.

What do I need to pass to my `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS)` field make this work? Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'host/script.php';
$post = array('image' => '@image.jpg');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```